# C# OleDb INSERT INTO overflow exception

Tags: c#, sql, database, oledb

My query looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblFiles (filename,downloadname,description,length,parts,checksum) 
VALUES ('IMG_0228.JPG','file1','description1'
        ,2694310,1925,26931139928208758813621215525179134210220)
```

I am using an access database and my table looks like this:

[image]

This is the exception I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Overflow

I do not understand what is causing this.

Comment: Your checksum datatype should be string/binary. Not number.

Comment: @lad2025 oh right because it exceeds the size of int. Solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with column datatype.

You tried to insert `26931139928208758813621215525179134210220` into number column which obviously generate overflow error.

You should change datatype of `checksum` column to `string/binary`.